# Jquery inputmask casing uppercase/lowercase

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

Im using [jquery inputmask](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)

How can I use below code to any input text with out a mask? any letter inputted will force to uppercase.

```
Inputmask.extendAliases({
  uppercase: {
            mask: '' // any letters
            definitions: {
                '*': {
                    casing: "upper" //
                }
        }
});
```

js

```
$('.uppercase').inputmask({casing:'upper'}); 
$('.lowercase').inputmask({casing:'lower'});
```

html

```
<input type="text" class="uppercase" />
<input type="text" class="lowercase" />
```

Comment: If you have a choice try https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs

Answer (score 2):

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.lowercase {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input class="uppercase" />
<input class="lowercase" />
<input class="capitalize" />
```

Use css.

Comment: css only applies in display text not in value. thanks anyways :)

Comment: `onblur="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"` for text value, it would work behind the scene.

Answer (score -2):

You can use @guradio css and just uppercase results on form submit on serverside or with JavaScript before submit.

Or just read https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask there examples, you can use regexp to limit only to uppercase letters.